# Who/what can affect a D.Va-less mech?

Tags: overwatch

I'm aware that a charging Reinhardt can push a self-destructing D.Va mech, and that Roadhog can hook it in an act of selfless sacrifice. And of course Mei's ice wall can stop it (and probably lift it, if timed correctly) But what about...

- Lucio's alt-fire
- Junkrat's mines and or traps
- Pharah's concussive blast

Do those or anything else that I missed have an effect on the mech?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Meka itself is not affected by any kind of knockback, so only Reinhardt's charge and Roadhog's hook can move it. Well, and I suppose physically pushing it with your hero's hitbox.

Comment: Ah, I see. So basically the same as a Sentry Bastion. That's too bad. I'd love to blast a self-destruct away with Pharah.

Comment: Mei's ice wall can also lift it.

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head but what about Zarya's ult too? I wouldn't think of that as a type of knockback.

Comment: I think Zarya ult does affect it too. Should test... But good idea.

Comment: If the mech was sent away from D.Va using her boosters [shift], it will apply knockback to players and destructables in its path, so just standing in its way won't affect its path.

Comment: You can't body-push a stationary mech, same as Bastion. Also, from my experience Zarya's ult doesn't move it either, but it is worth a test.

Comment: @KizTrap A Mech-less D.VA can move her own self destructing mech, if ever so slightly.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf do you mean boosting before self destruct or is there some other way?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Really? What a peculiar thing. You got a gif or vid of a D.Va pushing her mech, would love to see that

Comment: @KizTrap yes i do, i saw it on reddit a few weeks back. I'll find it again for you

Comment: @KizTrap [Here's a Gfy of it](https://gfycat.com/GivingFineIndianelephant)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Well I'll be... This opens up a whole world of options!

Comment: if they try to hide under the bridge they wont be expecting it to come down and explode next to where they're hiding